# Unable to execute php file after installing orientdb-php driver?

Tags: php, codeigniter, orientdb, orientdb-2.1

I have installed orientdb-php driver from https://github.com/AntonTerekhov/OrientDB-PHP using the composer.
But, in my php file when i am using code :
 "require 'OrientDB/OrientDB.php';" it is showing the following error:

```
require(OrientDB/OrientDB.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory.
```

Here is a [Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YerWX.png)

Comment: is the driver in the correct location?

Comment: Yes, I am using Codeigniter, and driver is present in vendor/orientdb-php folder.

Comment: composer already includes the libraries you include with it, so no need of the require here, you can directly start at `$db = new OrientDB(string $host[, int $port[, int $connectTimeout]]);`

Comment: If I use directly without including Orientdb.php, then it is throwing exception stating message as: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: Class 'USER' was not found in current database

Comment: Highlighted the error message.